# text underline breaks between lower case letters on html email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am having this issue where using text-decoration: underline is skipping spaces between lower case letters. I tried "text-decoration-skip-ink: none" that doesnt seem to work nor do I think thats the solution never seen this before. Not really sure how to troubleshoot this

```
    <td>
<b><span style="text-decoration: underline 1px; font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #1C2A5B; text-decoration-skip-ink: none;">Estrogen-Alone Therapy</span></b></td>
```

[image]

Comment: This works on chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Newcontributor OP is testing in emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good one. Not sure but I do have a solution for you. Instead of the underline, and since its a span, you can do the following:

Change your code from this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <b><span style="text-decoration: underline 1px; font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #1C2A5B; text-decoration-skip-ink: none; display:inline-block">Estrogen-Alone Therapy</span></b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

To this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <b><span style="border-bottom: 1px solid orange; padding-bottom:10px; font-size:15px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #1C2A5B; text-decoration-skip-ink: none; display:inline-block">Estrogen-Alone Therapy</span></b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And you can even adjust the spacing underneath your text. It's not necessarily a "Fix", but a workaround. All I did was that since the underline piece wasn't playing nice, I removed it, and added a border to the bottom, and padding to adjust the height/space between the word and the underline itself. It will look like this(before and after):
[image]

**Please note:** If this was an "A" tag that had the issue, you could also add `"display:inline-block;"` to it for the same effect. I didn't add it to this one because a span is already inline.

Happy coding.

Comment: thank you Mr Somdow this worked perfect as I am doing HTML email

Answer (score 2):

That is how the underlined is supposed to work.
I have tried it (see following snippet), and everything is working ok. On [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-decoration-skip-ink) it says it should work on all browsers, except on IE (are you by any change on Internet Explorer?)

```css
.class-name {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickless: 1px;
  color: #1C2A5B;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <b>
    <span class="class-name">Estrogen-Alone Therapy</span>
  </b>
</td>
```

An idea to fix the problem would be to use a `border-bottom`, or even an `::after` to replace the underline

Comment: This is for emails. That has a good support for browsers but not for emails. Please don't answer questions for emails with answers for web.  https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=text-decoration-skip-ink

Comment: @Syfer If we write the css inline on the element it shouldn't make a difference!

Comment: That's bogus. Email code get parsed by the email client, and changed. So each email client has a list of what elements and styles it supports, that list is less than what is normally supported on the general web.